# Failed to download libncurses5

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

I can't install ncurses library on my computer. When I compile it with make , I get a fatal error n.curses.h: No such file or directory.

I tried to install it via terminal, however I didn't succeed.
I've got this response: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5:i386`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5
E: Unable to locate package libncurses5:i386
```

I also tried to fix my source.list since I used:
`sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list`

However, it deleted everything on the file.
Searching on web I found this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

(...)

Copied and pasted on my source.list and placed '`#`' where it says `deb` or `deb-src`. Now, I can't download any software via terminal, can you help me?

---

`uname -a; arch`

```
Linux muca 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
x86_64
```

Comment: What is your CPU architecture? Please share output of `uname -a; arch` .

Comment: Hey, that's what I've got when I do that command you told me to do:  Linux muca 5.8.0-59-generic #66~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 17 11:14:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
x86_64

Answer (score 4):

So you are running 64-bit Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. You can restore default APT repositories using the following single long command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main universe multiverse restricted

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main universe multiverse restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main universe multiverse restricted
EOF
```

add 32-bit i386 architecture, update package lists using and install needed packages

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5:i386
```

Comment: Thank you! But in exchange it sent me this after sudo apt-get update: Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
 (...)
It 'fetched' all the files.
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Do you have internet on this computer?

Comment: It also isn't downloading or installing any software. Goddamn, it has been a lot of time I've been trying to solve this problem

Comment: I have internet on my computer, but on the virtual machine I don't.

Comment: Can you ping APT archive servers from VM by `ping -c3 archive.ubuntu.com` and `ping -c3 security.ubuntu.com`. For correct network configuration for VirtualBox follow https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html .

Comment: ping -c3 archive.ubuntu.com
ping: archive.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution ping -c3 security.ubuntu.com
ping: security.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution. 
Alright, I'll try to read and give it a shot. Thanks man.